# ColdFusion Web Service suddenly throwing error on invoke statement

Tags: web, service, coldfusion

I have created 3 ColdFusion Web Services while trying to learn. They worked great on Thursday, and then all of them threw errors on the invoke statement Friday. Are you supposed to just invoke once?

Here is the test service (hello.cfc):

```
<cfcomponent> 
<cffunction name="helloWorld" returnType="string" access="remote">
<cfreturn "Hello World!">
</cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

and here is the invoke (hello.cfm):

```
<cfset wsURL = "https://myurl/cfwack/4/hello.cfc?wsdl">
<cfinvoke
  webservice = "#wsURL#"
  method = "helloWorld"
  returnVariable = "result">
<cfoutput> <H1> #result# </H1></cfoutput>
```

**Error Dump:**

```
AxisFault faultCode: {schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope}Server.userException faultSubcode: 
faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file. 
faultActor: faultNode: faultDetail: {xml.apache.org/axis}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file. at

org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) at org
.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source) at org
.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) at org
.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) at

org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) at org
.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source) at org
.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at org
.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.pa... 

The specific sequence of files included or processed is: D:\HTTP\cfwack\4\hello.cfm, line: 6
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the code for the Hello.cfc webservice.

Comment: Here is some of the errors in the log..                                                               
 .AxisFault   faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException   faultSubcode:    faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.   faultActor:    faultNode:    faultDetail:    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.   at

Comment: Here is the rest:                                                                                                                                org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)   at

Comment: and more...                                                                                                                                         org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.pa... The specific sequence of files included or processed is: D:\HTTP\cfwack\4\hello.cfm, line: 6 "

Comment: When I try to bring up the wsdl, it is just blank.

Comment: Sos, what do you mean by "Looks like you forgot to post the code for the Hello.cfc webservice"?

Comment: `https://devweb02.emp.state.or.us/cfwack/4/hello.cfc?wsdl` was unreachable when I tried it. Consider putting a try/catch around the web service to see if it is having errors.

Comment: @CharlotteWilliams - You wrote `Here is the test service (hello.crc):` suggesting you meant to post the cfcomponent code inside Hello.cfc, but mistakenly posted the code for invoking it instead.

Comment: I copied the error messages from the comments to the main question. The error is simply: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.`. Possible that the XML file is not available at that URL for some reason or it does not load correctly for this request.

Comment: It worked the day I created it, and then stopped the next day without changes. I used this link for examples: https://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2031328&seqNum=3

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is the component... <cfcomponent>
   <cffunction name="helloWorld" returnType="string" access="remote">
      <cfreturn "Hello World!">
   </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

Comment: The cftry didn't do anything :(

Comment: What happens if you just browse to `https://myurl/cfwack/4/hello.cfc?method=helloWorld`?

Comment: When I browse https://myurl/cfwack/4/hello.cfc?method=helloWorld?, it works.

Comment: But isn't that not how a web service works? It worked before with myurl/cfwak/4/hello.cfc?wsdl